# Does not allow same product more than a one-time CodeIgniter shopping cart

Tags: php, jquery, html, codeigniter-3, shopping-cart

I am using the CodeIgniter shopping cart and below is the code which displaying my all the details on the browser.

(Just share the logic part)

```
<?php
   foreach ($post as $row) {?>
  <tr>
    <td><?php echo $i++;?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row->name;?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row->price;?></td>
    <td>
      <?php if($row->is_approved==1){?><button type="button" name="renew" class="btn btn-success add_cart">Add to cart</button>
      <?php }else{?>
      <div class="activity_status">Not Approved</div>
      <?php };?>
    </td>
  </tr>

  <div id="primarycart_details"></div>
  <?php}?>
```

I am getting the output on the browser

```
    Id | Name   | price  | Action
    1  | poimjh | 10     | Add to cart
    2  | asdasd | 100    | Add to cart
    3  | dgfdfw | 50     | Add to cart
    4  | qwewqe | 100    | Not Approved
   // and so on
```

Now My issue is, When I clicked on add to cart it's adding the product details in the cart and also I am changing the button status from `Add to cart` to `Remove`. Now When I refresh the page then my button again change from `Remove` to `Add to cart`. I don't want to add the same product more than one time.

**Ajax**

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
  $(document).on('click', '.add_cart', function() {
  var product_name = $(this).closest('tr').find('.productname').text();
  var product_id = $(this).closest('tr').find('.productid').val();
  var product_price = $(this).closest('tr').find('.calActivitylPrice').text();
      var quantity =1;
       $.ajax({
        url:"<?php echo base_url(); ?>Member_controller/addToCart",
        method:"POST",
        data:{product_id:product_id, product_name:product_name, product_price:product_price,quantity:quantity},
        success:function(data)
        {
            var obj = JSON.parse(data);
          //alert(data);
         $('#changeToRemove').html('<button type="button" name="remove" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs remove_inventory" id="'+obj.removebtn+'">Remove</button>')
         $('#primarycart_details').html(obj.subtotal);
        }
       });
     });
    });
```

**Remove code**

```
$(document).on('click', '.remove_inventory', function(){
  var row_id = $(this).attr("id");
  //alert(row_id);
  if(confirm("Are you sure you want to remove this?"))
  {
   $.ajax({
    url:"<?php echo base_url(); ?>Member_controller/Removecart",
    method:"POST",
    data:{row_id:row_id},
    success:function(data)
    {
     alert("Product removed from Cart");
    }
   });
  }
  else
  {
   return false;
  }
 });
```

**Remove from a cart in controller**

```
public function Removecart(){
 $row_id = $_POST["row_id"];
 //echo $row_id;
  $data = array(
   'rowid'  => $row_id,
   'qty'  => 0
  );
  //print_r($data);
  $this->cart->update($data);
  echo $this->viewCart();

}
```

**Add to cart code in controller**

```
public function addToCart(){
  $data = array(
   "id"  => $_POST["product_id"],
   "name"  => $_POST["product_name"],
    "qty"  => $_POST["quantity"],
   "price"  => $_POST["product_price"]
  );
  //print_r($data);
  $this->cart->insert($data); //return rowid 
  //echo $this->viewCart();
}
```

Can anyone help me out on this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make a conditional within the product loop like this :

```
<?php
foreach ($post as $row) {?>
<tr>
    <td><?php echo $i++;?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row->name;?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row->price;?></td>
    <td>
    <?php if($row->is_approved==1){
        if (in_array($row->id, array_column($this->cart->contents(), 'id'))) {
            $rowid = 0;
            foreach ($this->cart->contents() as $product) {if ($product['id'] === $row->id) { $rowid = $product['rowid']; break;}}
            ?>
        <button type="button" name="remove" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs remove_inventory" id="<?php echo $rowid; ?>">Remove</button>
        <?php } else { ?>
        <button type="button" name="renew" class="btn btn-success add_cart" data-productname="<?php echo $row->name; ?>" data-price="<?php echo $row->price;?>" data-productid="<?php echo $row->name_id; ?>" />Add to cart</button>
        <?php } ?>
    <?php }else{?>
    <div class="activity_status">Not Approved</div>
    <?php };?>
    </td>
</tr>

<div id="primarycart_details"></div>
<?php
}
```

First `array_column($this->cart->contents(), 'id')` is used to get an array list of product id, then apply `in_array()` on it to check whether current cart item is exist on product list or not.

And this line : `foreach ($this->cart->contents() as $product) {if ($product['id'] === $row->id) { $rowid = $product['rowid']; break;}}` is used to look up `rowid` value on each product.

Comment: give me some time to check

Comment: Yes, your code is working, but remove form the cart is not working now.

Comment: You didn't share the remove cart code, so I don't know how it should work, I just share example

Comment: I just updated my remove code. Using your code it's sending the id but to clear the records from the cart it's require rowid .

Comment: Your javascript remove code doesn't seems to be removing html code, it's just shows alert

Comment: Before adding your answer, What i did is when the user clicks on add to cart it will change the button from add to cart to Remove. Check my add to cart code in jquery. There is my Remove button and that is working because I am passing id="'+obj.removebtn+'" to the cart.

Comment: Then I uploaded question here because when I refresh the page it's changeing the button from Remove to Add to cart. Then I applied your answer,my refresh issue got resolved because you added remove button code and if I click on that button then that is not removing the records from cart.

Comment: may I know how did you get the `obj.removebtn`? could you update the question

Comment: maybe it's on `viewCart()` function?

Comment: Yes, That is in the viewCart and using JSON I am getting it. What is the best way can handle according to you?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186222/discussion-between-user9437856-and-hasta-dhana).

Comment: I tried your code but trust me it's not working. How you got $row->rowid? that is my main issue

Comment: Give me some time to check.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, $rowid = $product['rowid']; is displaying last rowid id.

Comment: What do you means by _$rowid = $product['rowid']; is displaying last rowid id_ ? does each button became having the same rowid?

Comment: I have more than 10 records and all are displaying in the table list. if the record is one then it works but if more the one records thenI am getting the last rowid. I am getting the last rowid on remove button because foreach is closed before the remove button.

Comment: Could you give a screenshot?